# cache reset button and question about deleting cache

Tags: cache

I need to put a "delete cache button" on front-end pages. I am looking for plugins for it. any experience or recommendation for it?
Can you recommend me a plug in when i create a reset button?

What if users keep deleting cache or allow users to delete cache, is it fine or causing any problems for wordpress sites?

We use super-cache and we have front end forms based on buddypress and others.
After users post, it is not displaying immediately. cuz of cache. then users may need to delete cache. therefore we are trying to find a plugin for users on front-end page.

Thank You.

Comment: you should probably be deleting cache on form submission, not leaving it to users to do.

Comment: any reason for it? so you mean there is no plugin like that for users?

Comment: it's poor user experience, and it's potentially a waste of server resources. any decent WordPress plugin will have actions that you can hook into to perform this operation, that's how supercache itself is able to regenerate the cache when you do something on the admin side. i've certainly never encountered a plugin that puts that sort of power in the user's hands. also note that plugin recommendations are [off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site.

Comment: ok thanks, I understand now. if you leave your comments as answers. I will select it as best answer. I think it helps to others as well. (to newbies like me :))
Thanks,